# Need to use multiple database in node mongodb/mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Well, i am stuck in little technical stuff let me explain.

i have one database with name of Company and in this i have two columns name and DBname and i have multiple Companies databases now i want to call company data based on Company DB.

i already have connected company databse like this in my main index.js

```
  const connect = mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/Company',
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false
  })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

but i have to change this connecting when user is logged in based on user company database

for this i am using a DB middleware like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let DB = (req, res, next) => {
    const connect = mongoose.createConnection( 'mongodb://localhost/company_ABC',
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false
      })
      .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
      next();
};

module.exports = { DB };
```

like this and it's not working please help me to resolve this issue and thanks in advance

Comment: Is the Company's DB and company_ABC's DB under the same connection string?

Comment: yes under the same connection

Answer (score 2):

Remove the DB name after the connection string.

```js
  const connect = mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/',
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false
  })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Select the database in your schema file instead and export it

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const db = mongoose.connection.useDb("company")
const collection = db.model('collectionName', collectionSchema);
module.exports = { collection };
```

```js
const { collection } = require('path-to-schema');

const files = await collection.find({})......
```

Comment: as i said i have to get database name from company database and then i have to get data in this case how i will get database name from company based on userID?